# How to use if statement and perform the following operation?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

How to use if loops and perform the following condition:

for example if i have the following datatype,

```
id    count A    count B    variable A     variable    sum
AAA    6           34         AA              AA        10
123    15          19         RA              RA        25
AAA    61          04         AA              AA        85
123    1           91         RS              RS        35
123    66          89         RA              RA        25
AAA    45          41         SP              SP        55
123    62          39         SS              SS        45
```

For the same id, if variable A and variable B are same and not same, i would like to perform this operation.

if variable A = variable B

```
df = df.assign(result = np.where(df.sum < 50, df.shift(1).count A, df.count A))
```

if variable A != variable B

```
df = df.assign(result = np.where(df.sum > 50, df.shift(1).count A, df.count A))
```

Comment: Are formulas same for each condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need add conditions with `()` and `&` (and):

```
m1 = (df['sum'] < 50)  & (df['variable A'] == df['variable B'])
df = df.assign(result = np.where(m1, df.shift(1)['count A'], df['count A']))

m2 = (df['sum'] > 50)  & (df['variable A'] != df['variable B'])
df = df.assign(result = np.where(m2, df.shift(1)['count A'], df['count A']))
```

Comment: Maybe think `df['count B']` instaed `df['count A']`